# Can Wolverine get exhausted by physical training?

Tags: marvel, x-men, wolverine, mutant

Wolverines (Logan) healing properties are well known. In physical training, there is a condition known as *Overtraining*:

> Overtraining is a result of not properly recovering between workouts on a repeated basis. Some types of workouts and training will make you more susceptible to overtraining, but the underlying cause is always a lack of recovery.
>
> From [RunnersConnect](https://runnersconnect.net/coach-corner/overtraining-causes-symptoms-and-how-to-dig-yourself-out/)

Is Wolverine able to have overtraining, i.e. get exhausted of physical activity or could he, theoretically, run e.g. a marathon with the same average speed as a 100m race as his muscles are not tiring as they recover constantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to his bio in the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z #13](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1_13)*:

> *He is partially immune to exertion-induced fatigue poisons and thus has greater endurance than ordinary humans.*

[image]

The use of the words "partially immune" suggest that while his endurance is greater than a normal man's, it isn't limitless. So, at some point, he presumably would begin to feel the effects of fatigue poisons, if he continued working out at a high level for long enough.

I doubt this has been covered in a story though. Aside from combat training with other X-Men and Avengers, I struggle to recall any scenes of Wolverine working out. What has been shown is that his healing factor does have limits. For example, when Magneto pulled all the adamantium out of his body in *[X-Men Vol 2 #25](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/X-Men_Vol_2_25)*, his healing factor was overloaded and burned out for a while.